# Is there a way to get more-specific error codes from Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE?

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I'm using an "ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE" intent to install an update to my own application (we can't use the Play store so we must side-load). I have an "onActivityResult()" method for handling the result, and it works fine for the "happy path" of regular installation.

But when there's a problem of some kind, the only 'resultCode' values I get are RESULT_OK (pass) or RESULT_FIRST_USER (fail).  I would like to know the specific reason for the failure so I can give the user better advice how to remedy it.

For example, when doing a roll back to a previous version of the app it will choke on the 'versionCode' and not allow the install. The advice in that case would be they need to uninstall and reinstall.  Unfortunately the 'resultCode' value for this failure is the same as if the user canceled the install, so I'm unable to give that advice.

Is there any way to get a more specific error code for this?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Bummer. It could be used for things like permissions not enabled as well (REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES starting in Oreo SDK).

Comment: Note that you can find out the `versionCode` in the APK to be installed via [`getPackageArchiveInfo()` on `PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageArchiveInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)). Similarly, you can find out about the permission problem [via `canRequestPackageInstalls()` on `PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#canRequestPackageInstalls()).